# IP white list for docker containers with iptables and ipset

Tags: iptables, firewall, docker, whitelist, ipset

I want to restrict access to docker container ports just from specified IPs.

I set up iptables rules with ipset.

I have exposed the port 8888. The requests from port 8888 are forwarded to simple docker web server.

I defined ipset with white list IP addresses.

```
ipset create testfilter iphash
ipset add testfilter 192.168.52.65
```

Then I created iptables rules. New chain with name `testfilter`, `FORWARD` rule with port `8888` should jump to `testfilter`. The first rule from `testfilter` chain should match IP from white list ipset. The second rule from `testfilter` chain should dropping communication when IP doesn't match with white list.

```
iptables -N testfilter
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8888 -j testfilter
iptables -A testfilter -m set --match-set test_ips src -j RETURN
iptables -A testfilter -j DROP
```

But port `8888` is still accessable from any IP. I also try to use `INPUT` rule instead of `FORWARD` rule, also remove `--dport` param from rule and put `-m state --state NEW` param instead of that. Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your 8888 port because your docker container is running on localhost and the FORWARD isn't blocking it. Please use -i option to specify lo interface.

Comment: I didn't specify interface in iptables rules. I have a suspicion about ports. The port `8888` is mapped on `8000`. Probably `FORWARD` rule should be defined for port `8000`.